# Not able to create asset (factory.newResource())

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to create an asset using a transaction but it is throwing an error:

`Error: Invalid or missing identifier for Type Temp in namespace org.acme.mynetwork`

Yesterday I updated my node packages from then it is not working. Any lead would be appreciated.

Model:

```
namespace org.acme.mynetwork

asset Temp identified by id {
    o String id
}
transaction Test {}
```

Script:

```
 /**
  * blah
  * @param {org.acme.mynetwork.Test} blah
  * @transaction
  */
 async function Test() {
   let factory = getFactory()
   let registry = await getAssetRegistry("org.acme.mynetwork.Temp")
   let resource = factory.newResource("org.acme.mynetwork","Temp",1)      //Error
   await registry.add(resource)
 }
```

Access Control

```
 rule Default {
     description: "Allow all participants access to all resources"
     participant: "ANY"
     operation: ALL
     resource: "org.acme.mynetwork.*"
     action: ALLOW
 }

 rule SystemACL {
   description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
   participant: "ANY"
   operation: ALL
   resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
   action: ALLOW
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your identifier is a String

therefore (tested this in Composer v0.18.x online at https://composer-playground-next.mybluemix.net/

```
 /**
 * blah
 * @param {org.acme.trading.Test} blah
 * @transaction
 */

async function Test() {
  let factory = getFactory();
  let registry = await getAssetRegistry("org.acme.trading.Temp");
  let resource = factory.newResource("org.acme.trading","Temp", 't1');      

  await registry.add(resource);
}
```